# Membership tab will not display

Tags: civimember

On a multisite with civimember enabled on that domain, the membership tab  on the contact summary screen does not show. I have ruled out Contact Layout Editor as a cause by disabling it. I have tried disabling and re-enabling the civimember component and clearing the caches.

I have a valid membership type on that domain too (not that that should matter)

What would be the cause for it not to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check:  https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpreferences%2Fdisplay&reset=1  and see if Membership is 'unchecked'

[image]